# Patch Antenna Inset Feed Past Exam Question

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

I'm trying to work out what 3.d) is meant to be.  I'm not entirely sure which part of the antenna it is referring to; I assume it's referring to width of the gap between the feed and the patch.  If this is the case, I have no idea what width one would want to make it.  I would've thought as small as possible to not perturb the antenna much.

As far as I can tell, the textbook we're using (Antenna Theory: Analysis And Design by Balanis) doesn't really talk about it, except for saying that it'll introduce some capacitance and perhaps shift the resonance by up to 1%.

[image: Question]
The red numbers are the lecturer's answers.  I'm not really sure how he got 13.36mm for 3.c).  I believe the inset should be about 9mm based on:

$$R_{in}(y=y_0) = R_{in}(y=0) \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{L}y_0\right)$$
$$75=150\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{40.1\text{m}}y_0\right)$$
$$y_0 \approx 9\text{mm}$$

I really have no idea about part 3.d) though.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm sorry, but... what?  We don't have your past exam papers to hand, so how are we supposed to know what "d" refers to?

Comment: I put an image.  Isn't it visible?  I meant '3.d)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure on 3c either.  I get 10.02mm for 75.06 ohms.  And if you flip it to use 42.1mm I get 10.52mm for 75.06 ohms.  Perhaps there is something we are both missing.

For part 3d, I think they are referring to the spacing around the feed line.  In this image, not d but the cut out gap "g" along the feed. This is sometimes also called the "notch width".  Usually you can specify the gap as a ratio of the width of the feed line.  Where you can set g=W/10, W/15,..W/40...etc.

[image: gap]

There are a number of ways to estimate the gap "g" for the design.  In general it effects the return loss's Q factor.  The smaller the gap the wider the S11 notch.

Here is an example from http://www.wseas.us/e-library/transactions/communications/2010/89-353.pdf

[image]

I'm not sure how your text or class is expecting you to estimate it without any design goals stated.  Perhaps they presented a typical estimate for "g" to center the S11 on your operating frequency?

Comment: Thank you!  Problem is, the lecturer never spoke about that width at any point or made mention to it in any of the material, bit of a joke really...  I saw in a few places they made 'g' the width of the feed, not sure if that has a good reason behind it.  I was thinking maybe I could pretend it's a capacitor and say I'd use the thickness of the copper and y_0 and substrate permitting and 'g' to work out a capacitance that's resonant at operating frequency. Maybe it's simply smaller is better...  I also get 10.02, makes me think he incorrectly marked last years exam.  Pretty bad really.